# Unbinding an event with Dojo

Tags: events, binding, dojo

I've used .on() to bind a keydown event in Dojo. After the event fires, I need to unbind the event, and nothing seems to work. Their documentation says that the event returns an object that has a .remove() method, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access or apply this method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    query('#video-topics-input').on('keydown',function(e){
        topicsDrop.keyDownFunc(e, e.keyCode);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dojo.on returns an event-handle which has the said .remove function to unbind a listener. in your case however, youre using a chained dojo.query which operates on a dojo.NodeList.

This basically means that you must think in terms of arrays, your above example would return an array with one entry - since selector is an ID.

To bind eventlistener:

```
var eventHandles = query('#video-topics-input').on('keydown',function(e){
        topicsDrop.keyDownFunc(e, e.keyCode);
});
```

And to unbind these:

```
eventHandles.forEach(function(handle) { handle.remove() });
```

A more efficient approach would be to not use query to look up byId though

Comment: Yeah, I'm a Dojo newbie...I ended up doing the above example using dom.byId to select the element. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: glad to be of help, still :) actually i usually have an 'onload' and 'onunload' functionality, sort of a ctor/dtor pattern to my objects/pages. this way you eliminate memoryleakages in ajax applications

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to add to @mschr's answer

as he mentioned, if you are looking up by id you should probably use `dojo/dom`'s `byid` function which returns a single domNode.  If you do this, you can also take advantage of `dojo/on`'s `once` function which [does exactly what it says](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on#once-function)-- It fires the event handler once then disconnects it.

```
require(['dojo/dom','dojo/on',function(dom,on){
  var node = dom.byId('video-topics-input');
  on.once(node, 'keydown',function(e){
    //some event handler that should only be fired once.
  });
});
```